# HTACCESS redirection adding unneccessary parametes in url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

htaccess to redirect our website traffic.

**We are redirecting EXAMPLE.com to www.EXAMPLE.com using following code**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]  -

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]*/)*index\.(html?|php)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*)index\.(html?|php)$  http://www.example.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```

**But we are facing Problem:
`EXAMPLE.com/XYZ` is redirected to `WWW.EXAMPLE.com/?url=XYZ` But It should be redirected to `WWW.EXAMPLE.COM/XYZ`**

**So We need to remove this unneccessary ?url=**

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is happening due to wrong order of rules. Keep redirect rules before routing ones:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]  -

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]*/)*index\.(html?|php)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*)index\.(html?|php)$  http://www.example.com/$1  [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for reply ,Ya I was sequencing it in wrong order now Its working.